# SQL parse string into fields

Tags: sql

I have a string `firstname.lastname@domain.com` and I would like to parse the string into 3 columns.

- column 1 - firstname
- column 2 - lastname
- column 3 - domain.com

I've tried several variations of using `RTRIM`, `SUBSTR` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with no success.  Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: What database engine are you using? Edit your question and add the database tag.

Comment: use parsename for t-sql

Comment: is all the data like that one example? no underscores, no multiple initials, nothing else to consider at all. You are unlikely to get an answer until you tell us which database because the string functions differ for each vendor.

Comment: What have you tried so far???  Tag properly with the dbms you use if you want answer.

Answer (score 0):

> using Parsename, Charindex, Right and Replace MSSQL 2012+ (for Parsename function)

```
declare @myemail varchar(50) = 'firstname.lastname@domain.com'

select parsename(replace(@myemail,right(@myemail,charindex('@',reverse(@myemail))),''),2) [firstname],
       parsename(replace(@myemail,right(@myemail,charindex('@',reverse(@myemail))),''),1) [Lastname],
       right(@myemail,charindex('@',reverse(@myemail))) [Domain]
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the database you're using, so I will answer this question in SQL Server:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(q.email, 1, CHARINDEX('.', q.email) - 1) AS firstname,
       SUBSTRING(q.email, CHARINDEX('.', q.email) + 1, CHARINDEX('@', q.email) - CHARINDEX('.', q.email) - 1) AS lastname,
       SUBSTRING(q.email, CHARINDEX('@', q.email) + 1, LEN(q.email)) AS domain
FROM (SELECT 'firstname.lastname@domain.com' AS email) q
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/772783/956838/). I hardcoded the table just for demo, but of course you will be selecting from your own table. This query assumes all data follow the same pattern.

And if you prefer to use `LEFT` and `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT LEFT(q.email, CHARINDEX('.', q.email) - 1) AS firstname,
       SUBSTRING(q.email, CHARINDEX('.', q.email) + 1, CHARINDEX('@', q.email) - CHARINDEX('.', q.email) - 1) AS lastname,
       RIGHT(q.email, LEN(q.email) - CHARINDEX('@', q.email)) AS domain
FROM (SELECT 'firstname.lastname@domain.com' AS email) q
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/772792/956851/).

Comment: Excellent!  That did the trick.  Thank everyone who responded.

Answer (score 0):

There would be several ways to do it. Like other folks have mentioned, it also depends on what database you are working on.

Here's oracle version that uses a combination of SUBSTR, INSTR, REVERSE, LENGTH functions.

```
SELECT 'FIRST_NAME.LASTNAME@domain.com' "FULL NAME" , 
SUBSTR('FIRST_NAME.LASTNAME@domain.com', 0, (INSTR('FIRST_NAME.LASTNAME@domain.com', '.')-1) ) "FIRST NAME ",
SUBSTR('FIRST_NAME.LASTNAME@domain.com' , (INSTR('FIRST_NAME.LASTNAME@domain.com' , '.')+1),  LENGTH(SUBSTR('FIRST_NAME.LASTNAME@domain.com', (INSTR('FIRST_NAME.LASTNAME@domain.com', '.')+1) )) - INSTR(REVERSE('FIRST_NAME.LASTNAME@domain.com'), '@')) as "LAST NAME",
SUBSTR('FIRST_NAME.LASTNAME@domain.com' , (INSTR('FIRST_NAME.LASTNAME@domain.com', '@')+1)) "DOMAIN NAME"
FROM DUAL
```

Hope this helps!